# Japanese and Korean character support

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, character-encoding, cjk

I'm getting �� as my output in Python. This is the code I'm using:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('list.html', 'r', encoding='cp932', errors='ignore') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    tags = soup.find_all('dt')
    for a in tags:
        title = a.text

        print(a.text)
```

I tried utf-16 but then I get this message:

```
UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

I couldn't solve it on my own.

Comment: first you could read it in `byte mode` to display there chars as hex code. Maybe it will show if this is really `cp932`

Comment: often html files have `<meta charcode="...">` to define what encoding is used in this file. You could display HTML even in Text Editor to check it.

Comment: maybe problem is not reading but displaying it. Maybe you don't have font to display these chars. Or maybe it needs to decode to correct encoding before displaying.